# Fixing presentation with AWK

Tags: bash, awk, geoip

I'm creating a little script that reads the contents of a file containing a list of domains. The domains are then piped through dig +short to extract their IP addresses, I then pipe each of the IP's through geoiplookup to get their county of origin, and use AWK to present them in the following format:

```
IP Address , Country
IP Address , Country
IP Address , Country
IP Address , Country
IP Address , Country

for domain in $(cat "$1"); do dig +short $domain | tr '\n' ' ' >> Blacklist.csv | geoiplookup $domain | awk 'NR==1{print ","$5,$6,$7,$8}' >> Blacklist.csv ; done
```

Right now, I'm having an issue with the first IP Address displaying at the bottom, like so:

```
           , Country
IP Address , Country
IP Address , Country
IP Address , Country
IP Address , Country
IP Address
```

Any ideas on how my presentation can be tidied up?

=======================================================================

**EDIT:**

[Running Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeygC.png)

[Output CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYQ6G.png) - As you can see, The IP Address in Cell A1 has been incorrectly placed in Cell A5

**EDIT 2: Samples**
Input File - Text File Containing List of Domains:

```
helloworld.com
rubyonrails.org
sublimetext.com
gnu.org
```

**DIG Output:**

```
ryan@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ for domain in $(cat stackdemo.txt); do dig +short $domain ; done
69.25.240.212
185.199.108.153
45.55.41.223
209.51.188.148
```

**Final Combined Output:**

```
ryan@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Demo$ cat Blacklist.csv 
,United States  
69.25.240.212 ,Netherlands   
185.199.108.153 ,United States  
45.55.41.223 ,United States  
209.51.188.148
```

=======================================================================

**NON DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
ryan@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Demo$ cat Blacklist.csv 
,United States  
69.25.240.212 ,Netherlands   
185.199.108.153 ,United States  
45.55.41.223 ,United States
```

209.51.188.148

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
ryan@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Demo$ cat Blacklist.csv 
209.51.188.148 ,United States  
69.25.240.212 ,Netherlands   
185.199.108.153 ,United States  
45.55.41.223 ,United States
```

Comment: If I get it correctly you want to run `dig` command for all ips in your Input_file. If this is the case then could you please mention dummy sample of input_file(with ips) and dummy sample of `dig` output in your post(for 1 IP and with final total output) and let us know then?

Comment: I don't understand `... | tr ... >> Blacklist.csv | geoiplookup`. Is the combination of `>>` and `|` really what you want?

Comment: Kindly post your samples(as text) in your post, do not post them in form of images or links please @NigerianWizard

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Samples posted

Comment: @NigerianWizard, ok let me re-phrase it. You are having list of domains which you are passing or want to pass to `dig` to get their ips. ONce you get those you are passing them to `geoiplookup`; Where you are facing issues in re-arrnaging its output, Am I right? If yes then you can simply tell us `NON desired output` then `Desired output` since it is still not clear in your post. Because in your expected output somewhere ip or somewhere country is missing so not clear, please provide more details.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13Yes, this is correct, I have added the Non desired and desired outputs to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Still not fully clear to me, assuming that your `dig` command and your `geoiplookup` commands will NOT give empty output, if this is the case try.

```
while read line
do
   dig "$line" > "dig_output"
   geoiplookup "$line" > "lookup_output"
done < "domain_file"
```

Now combine output by doing:

```
paste -d"," "dig_output"  "lookup_output"
```

Fair warning: I haven't tested it since lack of softwares.

Comment: @NigerianWizard, could you please try above once and let me know? In case this is not working then paste output of `dig +short $domain | tr '\n' ' ' >> Blacklist.csv | geoiplookup $domain` once too?